# Executing javascript countdown script multiple times inside a loop

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony4

I'm using Symfony and I'm currently trying to show these elements from the database, but there's a twist here, since every one of these elements has a duration, and I have to show a countdown for that duration.

I already implemented the countdown script (even though it still has a few problems) but it only executes with the first value while the fields stays empty in the other rows.

I'll explain the code now: I have many parkings, each parking has many cars (voitures): my page shows the parkings, the cars related to them and for each car its number and a coutdown of the time that car's allowed (the time is registered in a column in the database).

I'm also using cookies in my script to save minutes and seconds so I don't know how to do it for multiple values.
here's a pic of what I did:

> [image]

here's my code (sorry it's messy):

```
{% extends 'Agent/Baseagent.html.twig' %}

{% block title %}Parking index{% endblock %}

{% block body %}

    {% for parking in user.parkings %}
         <h2>Parking</h2>
             {{ parking.libelle }}

              <h2>voitures</h2>
<table id="file_export" class="table table-striped table-bordered">
                <thead>

                <tbody>
            {% for voitures in parking.voitures %}
                <tr>
                <td>
               {{ voitures.matricule }}
                </td>


                <td>
                <div id="timer" class="js-user-rating" data-is-test="{{ voitures.time}}"></div>
                <td class="center"><span id="demo"></span></td>

                 <script>
 var firstTime = true;

function countdown(minutes) {
    var seconds = 60;
    var mins = minutes;

    if(firstTime && getCookie("minutes")&&getCookie("seconds"))
    {
            firstTime = false;

         var seconds = getCookie("seconds");
         var mins = getCookie("minutes");
    }

    function tick() {

        var counter = document.getElementById("timer");
        setCookie("minutes",mins,10)
        setCookie("seconds",seconds,10)
        var current_minutes = mins-1
        seconds--;
        counter.innerHTML = 
        current_minutes.toString() + ":" + (seconds < 10 ? "0" : "") + String(seconds);
        //save the time in cookie



        if( seconds > 0 ) {
            setTimeout(tick, 1000);
        } else {

            if(mins > 1){

               // countdown(mins-1);   never reach “00″ issue solved:Contributed by Victor Streithorst    
               setTimeout(function () { countdown(mins - 1); }, 1000);

            }
        }
    }
    tick();
}
function setCookie(cname,cvalue,exdays) {
    var d = new Date();
    d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays*24*60*60*1000));
    var expires = "expires=" + d.toGMTString();
    document.cookie = cname+"="+cvalue+"; "+expires;
}
 function getCookie(cname) {
    var name = cname + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i=0; i<ca.length; i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1);
        if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
            return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
        }
    }
    return "";
}
countdown(55);
                 </script>

                </td>
                </tr>
             {% endfor %}
        {% else %}
            <tr>
                <td colspan="6">no records found</td>
            </tr>
        {% endfor %}
                </tbody>
            </table>{% endblock %}
```

My Voiture Entity

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\VoitureRepository")
 */
class Voiture
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=200)
     */
    private $matricule;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
     */
    private $gareele;



    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Parking", inversedBy="voitures")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    private $parking;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="boolean")
     */
    private $parked;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $time;



    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getMatricule(): ?string
    {
        return $this->matricule;
    }

    public function setMatricule(string $matricule): self
    {
        $this->matricule = $matricule;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getGareele(): ?\DateTimeInterface
    {
        return $this->gareele;
    }

    public function setGareele(\DateTimeInterface $gareele): self
    {
        $this->gareele = $gareele;

        return $this;
    }



    public function getParking(): ?Parking
    {
        return $this->parking;
    }

    public function setParking(?Parking $parking): self
    {
        $this->parking = $parking;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getParked(): ?bool
    {
        return $this->parked;
    }

    public function setParked(bool $parked): self
    {
        $this->parked = $parked;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getTime(): ?int
    {
        return $this->time;
    }

    public function setTime(int $time): self
    {
        $this->time = $time;

        return $this;
    }


}
```

and my controller (it's nothing special, just get the parkings related to the connected user) :

```
/**
 * @Route("/agent")
 */
class AgentController extends AbstractController
{
    /**
     * @Route("/", name="agent", methods={"GET"})
     */
    public function index(): Response
    {

        $use = $this->get('security.token_storage')->getToken()->getUser();

        $user = $this->getUser();   
        $parkingz=$this->getUser()->getParkings();

        return $this->render('Agent/Agent.html.twig', [
            'user' => $user,
            'parkingz'=>$parkingz,
        ]);
    }
```

Comment: You are not going to get accurate times relying on `setTimeout` as that defines the amount of time that passes between each tick without regard to how long it takes to process the tick. It would be much better if you first determined the expiration timestamp for each car and then repeatedly call an update function to calculate the remaining time from the current time to the expiration time.

Comment: If you share your entity structure for voitures, and the controller action that renders the template above, I can provide a much cleaner solution.

Comment: Hi, I edited it and added the entity and the controller. As you can see, each car has an integer caller time which means how many minutes that car is going to stay parked, I still didn't implement that in the javascript since I still haven't gotten around to passing that value to the script.

Comment: So parking is valid for `Voiture->getTime()` minutes starting from `Voiture->getGareele()` is this correct?

Comment: correct, Time property is integer since I intend to use minutes and then add them in javascript with setMinutes().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have some nesting issues (the script tag needs to come out of the for loop), repeated ids, and an inaccurate timing system. If you need things to update to real-time use a timestamp along with the system clock to determine actual remaining time.

First add a method to your entity to get the expiration timestamp (will be in seconds)

```
class Voiture
{
  ...

  public function getExpiresAt()
  {
    $gareele = $this->getGareele();
    $expires = clone $gareele;
    $expires->modify('+' . $this->getTime() . ' min');

    return $expires->format('U');
  }
}
```

Then in the template, change the timer span to have `class="timer"` (no id is needed), and add a data attribute with the expiration timestamp. The script will loop through all `.timer`s and update the text to reflect the remaining days, hours, minutes, and seconds as of that moment in time. Here I'm updating the texts every 100 milliseconds by using `setTimeout()` inside the function.

```
{% extends 'Agent/Baseagent.html.twig' %}

{% block title %}Parking index{% endblock %}

{% block body %}

  {% for parking in user.parkings %}
    <h2>Parking</h2>
    {{ parking.libelle }}

    <h2>voitures</h2>
    <table id="file_export" class="table table-striped table-bordered">
      <thead></thead>

      <tbody>
      {% if parking.voitures|length > 0 %}
        {% for voitures in parking.voitures %}
          <tr>
            <td>
              {{ voitures.matricule }}
            </td>
            <td class="center">
              <span class="timer" data-expires="{{ voitures.getExpiresAt() }}"></span>
            </td>
          </tr>
        {% endfor %}
      {% else %}
        <tr>
          <td colspan="6">no records found</td>
        </tr>
      {% endif %}
      </tbody>
    </table>
  {% endfor %}

  <script>
    var timers = document.querySelectorAll('.timer')

    function updateTimers () {
      var rightNow = Math.floor(Date.now()/1000) // in seconds
      timers.forEach(function (timer) {

        var expires = parseInt(timer.dataset.expires) // in seconds

        if (rightNow > expires) {
          // Time expired
          timer.innerText = 'Expired'
        } else {
          var seconds = expires - rightNow
          var minutes = Math.floor(seconds/60)
          var hours = Math.floor(minutes/60)
          var days = Math.floor(hours/24)
          seconds = ('0' + String(seconds%60)).slice(-2)
          minutes = ('0' + String(minutes%60)).slice(-2)
          hours = ('0' + String(hours%24)).slice(-2)
          timer.innerText = days + 'd ' + hours + 'h ' + minutes + 'm ' + seconds + 's'
        }

      })

      setTimeout(function () {
        updateTimers()
      }, 100)
    }

    updateTimers()
  </script>

{% endblock %}
```

**Note**

If you are going to be adding more timers via ajax(after the page loads) you should place the line:

`var timers = document.querySelectorAll('.timer')`

inside the function block, to search for new timers on every call.

Comment: wow the function actually works for all of them with one small exception, the value is in the thousands, do you have any idea why that's happening ? here's a pic of the error and my database

Comment: @Hyperion is this value in minutes `Voiture->getTime()`? and what is the maximum time you want to support?

Comment: well, it's in Integer but yeah it's supposed to be in minutes. As for the maximum time it depends on the parking, since each parking has it's own max Time. like this https://imgur.com/a/25PJN7u

Comment: oh Also the inserting the data is supposed to be done using SMS so I don't think you should worry about that

Comment: @Hyperion I added support for longer times (days & hours)

Comment: the values are still inflated for some reason https://imgur.com/a/ujGwOEI, but it's okay, I'll try to make it work. you've helped me get through the hard part. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

There are duplicate id's  ("test","demo"), one for each voiture.

[From MDN doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id):

> The id global attribute defines a unique identifier (ID) which must be
>   unique in the whole document. Its purpose is to identify the element
>   when linking (using a fragment identifier), scripting, or styling
>   (with CSS).

This `document.getElementById("demo")` is going to return one result, probably the first one in the DOM. (I suspect that is also true here `var test = $('#test').data("isTest");` but I'm not fluent in jQuery).

Perhaps you could do selection(s) by "name" attribute,and change the code to have one `<script>` element that iterates through the desired nodes.